# Передать родительскому элементу из дочернего state с помощью React.createContext

Tags: reactjs

Необходимо сквозь несколько компонентов передать родителю state с массивом.
Если для этого нельзя использовать контекст, то хотя бы увидеть передачу через промежуточные компоненты.
Есть главный компонент MainColumns

```
class MainColumns extends Component {
state = {
    categories: [],
    subcategories: [],
    products: []
};

componentDidMount() {

    this.getCategories()
        .then(res => this.setState({ categories: res }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    this.getProducts()
        .then(res => this.setState({ products: res }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

getCategories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/store/getCategories');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body;
};

getProducts = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/store/getProducts');
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body;
};

render() {

    return (
        <div className="Main-columns">

            <div className="Category-column">
                <Link onClick={this.getCategories} to=''><p>All category</p></Link>
                <CategoryContainer data={this.state.categories}/>
            </div>

            <div className="Product-column">
                <ProductContainer data={this.state.products}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Компоненты CategoryContainer и ProductContainer выдают согласно количеству объектов в массиве div-ы с информацией.

```
class CategoryContainer extends Component {

componentDidMount() {}
render() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    let categoryTemplate;

    if (data.length > 0) {
        categoryTemplate = data.map(function (item, index) {
            return (
                <div className="category-container" key={index}>
                    <CategoryArticle data={item}/>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
    else {categoryTemplate = <p>No categories!</p>}

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {categoryTemplate}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
}
```

И уже в CategoryArticle есть ссылка на запрос конкретной категории. Туда же приходит массив с товарами. Необходимо передать его в state MainColumns.

```
class CategoryArticle extends Component {
getSpecificProduct = async () => {

    let categoryName = this.props.data.categoryName;
    const response = await fetch('/store/getSpecificProducts', {
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({categoryName: categoryName})
    });
    const body = await response.json();

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw Error(body.message)
    }
    return body;
//сюда приходит массив с товарами
};

render() {
let categoryName = this.props.data.categoryName;
return(
        <Link className ='category__name' to=''
              onClick={this.getSpecificProduct}>
            {categoryName}</Link>
)
}
}
```

Я находил информацию по данной теме, но она обрывочная. Не могу сам нормально написать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В компоненте, после получения данных необходимо вызвать обработчик, пришедший в props:

```
class CategoryArticle extends Component {
    getSpecificProduct = async () => {
        ...    
        // После закачки данных вызываем функцию, переданную в props
        if(typeof this.props.onBodyLoad === 'function') {
            this.props.onBodyLoad(body);
        }
        ...
    };

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

В CategoryContainer просто пробросим обработчик родительского компонента в CategoryArticles

```
class CategoryContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {}
    render() {
        ...
        if (data.length > 0) {
            categoryTemplate = data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div className="category-container" key={index}>
                        <CategoryArticle 
                            onBodyLoad={this.props.onBodyLoad} // здесь передаем обработчик из главного контейнера
                            data={item}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

а вот здесь собственно напишем обработчик

```
class MainColumns extends Component {
    onBodyLoad = (body) => {
        someActionWithBody(body);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
                <CategoryContainer 
                    onBodyLoad={this.onBodyLoad} // Передадим обработчик в дочерние компоненты
                    data={this.state.categories}
                />
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Дмитрий, возникает ошибка в CategoryContainer так как он создаёт отдельные div в которых лежат CategoryArticle поэтому - 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/components/article.js:17
  14 |     <div className="category-container"
  15 |          key={index}>
  16 |         <CategoryArticle
> 17 |             onBodyLoad={this.props.onBodyLoad}
  18 |             data={item}/>
  19 |     </div>
  20 | )
В браузере просмотрел код через react dev tools
в этих div отсутствует prop - onBodyload
он есть только в компоненте CategoryContainer

Comment: как передать props через созданные CategoryContainer div-ы

Comment: извиняюсь за спам, первый раз пользуюсь стаком, не знаю получили ли уводомление о комментарии

Comment: исправил. вместо `data.map(function(item, index) {` поставил стрелочную функцию `data.map((item, index) => {` иначе не передавался контекст this